# Inject a step into login

Tags: php, laravel-passport, laravel-6.2

I'm trying to perform an action the first time a user logs into my api. I'm using Laravel 6.2 with Passport via the password grant authorization method.

My user model has the following fields.

`id`,
`username`,
`display_name`,
`firstname`,
`lastname`,
`display_picture`,
`locked`,
`email`,
`last_login`,
`created_at`,
`updated_at`,
`deleted_at`

Initially I thought the best place to initiate that would be right before the login token is sent to the user, however as the user has never logged in before the last_login field would be null. However the problem is because the token is never sent back to the user at this stage I have no way of confirming the users' token when they get to the create stage. So my request guard doesn't have the logged in user information.

```
Auth()->guard('api')->user();
```

i.e. that returns null. Any idea on how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is not Laravel-specific, but your question reminded me of a problem I solved some time ago.

What I did was implemented a `last_seen` field on the user object - this field was not populated upon user creation, or account validation. It was instead populated on log-in and meaningful activity if the cookie is old.

If this field was empty when the user logged in, instead of sending them to the user area, I sent them to the tutorial and then updated the field - if the field was already populated, then I simply updated the field and sent them along to the user area.

---

This same field could be replaced with a calculated variable assuming user actions are logged in any meaningful way.

<sub>Plus, this is a useful value both for deactivating unused accounts and "status" if the platform is social.</sub>